# Typescript: extend interface within own d.ts file

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extend an interface, in particular: moment.Moment, to add a new method:

app.js:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./tools.d.ts" />

console.log(moment().isWeekend());
```

tools.d.ts:

```
declare module moment {
  interface Moment {
    isWeekend(): boolean;
  }
}
```

But I get this error when compiling:

```
Property 'isWeekend' does not exist on type 'Moment'
```

What step am I missing here to make sure this method gets added to the Moment interface?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem was that in my tools.d.ts file i was referencing other .ts files, which then referred to things in the tools.d.ts file that hadn't been processed yet.

Answer (score -1):

isWeekend is a function, you have to declare a function type like below,

```
  isWeekend : () => boolean;
```

To Read more go to [Function Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html)

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but the interface method declaration itself is fine as it is, I do know that for sure. Ctrl-F for "interface Something" on the page you linked, and you'll see the example.

Comment: wow, good to know, why are you using a module moment as a function? Can that be cause of problem? Cant you declare a moment function the return type of which is of Moment interface type?